# JPA - Get values from fields in other entities in a Controller class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have two entities: Room and Service. I also have a method in Logic class that i want to use in ServiceController class. Other classes are irrelevant.

room.getBeds() always returns 0, default int value.

Room entity:

```
@Entity
public class Room {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int room_id;

    private int beds;
    private int number;

    public Room() {
    }

    public Room(int beds, int number) {
        this.beds = beds;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public int getRoom_id() {
        return room_id;
    }

    public void setRoom_id(int room_id) {
        this.room_id = room_id;
    }

    public int getBeds() {
        return beds;
    }

    public void setBeds(int beds) {
        this.beds = beds;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

Service entity:

```
@Entity
public class Service {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    private int service_id;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy", timezone = "Europe/Berlin")
    private Date arrival_at;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy", timezone = "Europe/Berlin")
    private Date departure_at;

    private int meals;
    private int guest_id;
    private double price;

    public int getService_id() {
        return service_id;
    }

    public void setService_id(int service_id) {
        this.service_id = service_id;
    }

    public Date getArrival_at() {
        return arrival_at;
    }

    public void setArrival_at(Date arrival_at) {
        this.arrival_at = arrival_at;
    }

    public Date getDeparture_at() {
        return departure_at;
    }

    public void setDeparture_at(Date departure_at) {
        this.departure_at = departure_at;
    }

    public int getMeals() {
        return meals;
    }

    public void setMeals(int meals) {
        this.meals = meals;
    }

    public int getGuest_id() {
        return guest_id;
    }

    public void setGuest_id(int guest_id) {
        this.guest_id = guest_id;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

Service controller:

```
@RestController
public class ServiceController {

@Autowired
ServiceRepository serviceRepository;
private Logic logic = new Logic();
private Room room = new Room();

//CREATE
@PostMapping("/services")
public int createService(@RequestBody Service service) {

    service.setPrice(logic.calculatePrice(service.getArrival_at(), service.getDeparture_at(), room.getBeds(), service.getMeals()));

    return serviceRepository.save(service);
}
}
```

How to get the correct value from room.getBeds() getter?

Comment: Where do you populate your `room` object? You are just creating a new object and that's it. You have to populate it.

Comment: @ConstantinBeer I have a RoomController class with just CRUD funcions.

Comment: And also a RoomRepository? You have to call it in your ServiceController to populate your room object.

Comment: @ConstantinBeer Yes.

Comment: Could you provide those classes in your question.

Comment: @ConstantinBeer Populate Room object with what? I want to get the value of beds field in Room table and populate it with that.

Comment: With whatever you are trying to get. I assume you have a db with a room table that contains the information you want. But in your code you don't populate your `room` object with that. How do you think the information from your room table gets into your `room` object?

Answer (score 1):

Lerius you are just making a new object of Room Entity and are not populating any  values from your Database to that object 
                that is the reason why it is taking room.getBeds(); as 0(i.e default value for int)
                Try Populating DB values to your object after that you will be able to get the value of getBeds();